# getting error as a "useCounter" is read-only."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme

I make a simple demo of counter I am using `jest and enzyme` for testing.I want to know if I click `increment` button it call `increment` button handler. but it is giving me this error

**useCounter" is read-only**.

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-jepsen-5os4e?file=/src/App.test.js

```
test("clicking button increment counter  i call increment function", () => {
  const f1 = jest.fn();
  useCounter = jest.fn(() => {
    return {
      state: "",
      increment: f1,
      decrement: null
    };
  });

  const wrapper = setup();

  // find button and click
  const button = findByTestAttr(wrapper, "increment-button");
  button.simulate("click");

  // find display and test value
  expect(f1).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your sandbox example, it seems you are already importing `useCounter`

like `import useCounter from "./useCounter";`

And, then you're trying to update that variable(which isn't possible to do)

You should update your code like this

```
import * as counter from './useCounter' // declare named exports in useCounter
const f1 = jest.fn();
counter.useCounter = jest.fn(() => {
  f1,
});
```

Comment: still not working https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-jepsen-5os4e?file=/src/App.test.js

Answer (score 0):

Try to spy on it (and make sure it's not an arrow function):

```
jest.spyOn(useCounter, 'useCounter').mockImplementation(() => {
    //your mock implementation
});
```